# Beyond Compare 2 ignore case

Tags: beyondcompare

How can you get Beyond Compare 2 to ignore differences in letters case? E.g. "Foo Bar" and "fOo BAR" would be considered the same.

Comment: Does it not do this if you select Ignore Unimportant Differences?

Comment: Celeritas, sgmoore, @JohnD any idea how to achieve the same using Command Line Arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the type of file you are editing.

If you go to Tools/Options and Rules and work out which rule is applied to the files you are comparing and then see what is selected on the importance tab.

For example, if you edit/view the rules for Visual Basic files, you should see that Character case is ticked as being unimportant, but this is not ticked for C/C++ files.

So you may want to change the setting on the rule that BC is using, or else create a new rule for your type of file and select this option and then select ignore unimportant differences when you are comparing the files.

Answer (score 8):

In the version of BeyondCompare that I have (version 3.3 Pro), you can select "Text important, except for character case".  To find this setting, click on the Rules toolbar button, then pick "Edit Default".  Seen screenshot...

This option only appears in the "Data compare" settings.

[image]

If you are doing "Text compare", then you should make sure that "Character case" is not selected in the "Imporantance" tab, then choose "Ignore Unimportant Differences" -- that will do a case-insensitive compare.

[image]