# How to ignore capitalization in Beyond Compare 4

Tags: beyondcompare4

BC4 is currently highlighting lines, even when they differ only by capitalization. I want to ignore those.

- In Session Settings, I have UN-checked the box labeled "Character Case".
- I have selected the "Minor" button (sub-text: "Ignore unimportant Differences").
- I have ensured that the file type (.cs file) corresponds to the rules selected (as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831072/93394)).

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*So, I got an answer straight from Scooter support community:*

The character case check box only affects default text (text that isn't a string, identifier, comment, etc).

To ignore character case for non-default text, click the Edit Grammar button.
In the Grammar tab, select the grammar definition that matches the text that should ignore character case, such as Identifier.

- Click the Gear icon.
- Uncheck This element is case sensitive.
- Click OK until you're back to the main window

Answer (score 1):

For the `.cs` file type, in Session Settings, you will also need to uncheck the box labeled "Identifier" *(this is in addition to selecting the "Minor" button as already stated)*.

This is not necessary for some other file types, such as "HTML", "MS Word Documents", "RTF", "XML", and of course "Everything Else". Simply selecting the "Minor" button will ignore character case.

Comment: Thanks. While this gets close, it ends up ignoring ALL identifier changes. I only want to ignore them if they only change capitalization.

Comment: Goodness! That's crazy.

Comment: Not so crazy. If a developer changes the case of an identifier that is referenced dozens of times across the code base, it can really bloat the review.

Comment: My apologies. I did not mean *you* were crazy for ignoring the differences. It is the program that is crazy.